# windows safari browser shows x blocks in place of text

Tags: css, safari, font-face, font-family

This happens in windows 7 safari.

[image]

I checked the web inspector network tab, everything is retrieved successfully and there are no errors in the console.

Has anyone ran into anything like this?

This is using Gotham A, B webfont.

Comment: Windows Safari hasn't been supported by Apple for about 2 years now, so I'm sure there are probably many bugs like this. I'm not sure that it is worth us supporting if Apple doesn't.